# A Cloud OS to Install on my Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, webserver, cloud

Wondering if anyone has any experience or knowledge of some good, free, potentially open-source, cloud/Web Operating Systems that I can install and host on my own personal 2K8 R2 Server at home?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that you think a "Cloud OS" will help?

Comment: So I can access an OS (customisable through my server with applications and storage) through any browser on any computer.

Comment: You are using a very expensive server 2008 license and look for 'something cloud related but free'? Really ?

Comment: The cloud-wash gets in my eyes... What is a web os? Something I've probably been using for years that's been renamed somehow?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're actually after is a virtualization solution.

By installing something like VMWare or VirtualBox, you could have several customised "operating systems" accessible remotely running on your server.

e.g. You could have a Linux console-only VM, a Windows 7 VM with Office, and a Mac VM with Xcode all running on your server, and accessible remotely.

As far as accessing these through the browser, VMWare provides a tool called "vSphere Web Access", however it requires [VMWare ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/esxi-and-esx/index.html), which is not free.

VirtualBox supports it's own RDP protocol called vRDP, however it isn't accessible through a web browser, and vRDP clients seem to be pretty scarce.

More info on vRDP is available in the [VirtualBox manual, ch 7](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html).

Alternately, you could use an OS-native remote solution. Versions of Windows from XP upwards support Microsofts RDP protocol, and viewers are built into certain versions of the operating system.

Finally, probably the best route compatibility-wise would be to use a VNC client such as [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/)

This is a multi-platform VNC client/server which specifically has a Java viewer, which will run on any computer running Java. The server also comes with a built in web server.

From their website...

> The VNC servers also contain a small Web server. If you connect to it
>   with a web browser, the Java version of the viewer will be downloaded
>   automatically, allowing you to access the remote desktop. Obviously,
>   your Web browser must support Java applets. Also, you should not use a
>   proxy, to let the Java applet access the remote server directly.